# How to Sync Google Calendar, Yahoo Calendar and Toodledo in Iphone native app?

Tags: iphone, synchronization, icalendar

Hi i have googled many websites but have not found any api. i tried  http://code.google.com/p/iphone-gcal/ but it has some missing files of `GData`. I also integrated 
 http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/downloads/list?can=1&q=&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+ReleaseDate+Size+DownloadCount but its window based app.

Can any1 give me an api? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have sync google but yahoo n other is left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/iphone-gcal/wiki/GettingStarted

try it..

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to sync your Toodledo iPhone app with Toodledo.com. Then use Toodledo's calendar sync tools to sync the calendar with both Google and Yahoo.

http://www.toodledo.com/tools/sync_ical.php